# Inherit super constructor in extended class

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance, constructor

I have a scenario where I simply want to introduce new pure functions to a class. I can do this through inheritance

```
class BaseModule {
    constructor(
        public a: number,
        public b: number
    ) { }
    methodX(): void {
        // ...
     }
    methodY(): void {
        // ...
    }
}
class DerivedModule extends BaseModule {
    constructor(
        public a: number,
        public b: number,
    ) { // no additional dependencies
        super(a, b)
    }
    methodZ(): void { // additional behavior
        // ...
    }
    // methodX(), methodY() are automatically still available through inheritance
}
```

but this involves extra overhead in re-implementing an identical constructor, given that no additional dependencies are introduced in `DerivedClass`.

It also violates the open-closed principle, as every change that I may make to the parameters of `BaseModule` in the future will require going back to make respective changes to `DerivedModule`.

I would like `new DerivedClass()` calls to simply delegate to `new BaseClass()`, essentially omitting a constructor implementation in `DerivedClass` and inheriting the constructor of `BaseClass`.

I assume this is not possible, but wanted to confirm and see if there are any other techniques available.

Comment: If you omit the constructor from the child class then the parent one is inherited